# Java web application : managing picture/thumbnail galleries

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm pretty new to Java web application and I just started a sample project in order to get some experience in this area.

Here's the matter on which I am currently working : let's assume that my web application will display a bunch of items with a grid containing a small picture (thumbnail) for each of them. What are the best or common practices to implement such an application, with consideration for performance issues (here, I'm mainly thinking about the payload size every time a user would load the list of items)?

Do we usually create a smaller size copy of the uploaded image files, or do we use some Javascript, CSS transformation, you name it, to reduce the images to display?

FYI, I'm using Spring MVC for my sample project.

Hope my question was clear enough. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to create a separate thumbnail file for each picture when uploaded. When your client will display your gallery, he will only get reduced picture, and then save a lot of download and presentation time